# Extract a variable value from a text

Tags: batch-file

it's quite complicated....using a batch script on windows platform, I need to extract a variable string from an output file, editing the final result towards another file.

Example, the file text.log comes to me filled in this way:

```
C:Windows\xfile\CODSSD1.XXX
C:Windows\xfile\RPDDFSS.XXX
C:Windows\xfile\XCCLDJW.XXX
```

I need to catch only the last word in all rows, editing them in this manner:

```
XXXCODSSD1 
XXXRPDDFSS
XXX......
```

I've tried different commands but I'm not an expert.
Thank you very much!
Kind regards.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your output file named `text.log`, I would suggest something similar to the following:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("text.log"
) Do For /F "Tokens=* Delims=." %%B In ("%%~xA%%~nA") Do Echo %%B
Pause
```

*I have split the `For` loop over two lines only to maintain line length within 80 characters. Whilst it isn't a requirement, It's a best practice preference.*

**Edit**

To test it at the command prompt, you can use this single line:

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %A In ("text.log") Do @For /F "Tokens=* Delims=." %B In ("%~xA%~nA") Do @Echo %B
```

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable Support!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple one line `FOR` command using the /F option to read the file.  You can use the FOR command modifiers to break up the file name into its individual parts.  The `x` modifier is for the file extension.  The `n` modifier is for the base file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("text.log") DO (
    set "var=%%~xG%%~nG"
    echo !var:~1!
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you Squashman, but I receive the error "%%G was unexpected at this time"

Comment: @J.Doe, your question was tagged batch-file. You received that error because you ran it at the command prompt and not from a batch file! Try using this to test it at the command prompt: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %G IN ("text.log") DO echo %~xG%~nG`. _(either way, you'll find that the result will be incorrect; showing a **`.`** at the beginning. See my answer which doesn't.)_

Comment: @Compo, I totally forgot it includes the period in the modifier. You could have at least given me a chance to correct it instead of posting an answer yourself. I think I have at least earned that courtesy.

Comment: @Squashman, I'm happy to delete my answer, if you'd prefer it. Also, you may wish to rectify your 'one line' statement, as it's no longer relative to the modified code.